# Active Admin after filtering record, would like to go back(Withe the filter filtered in and with the search result) after save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin

When I used one of the filters, then edited one of the result.
How to I go back to the above place after saving the edited record?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Kwan your question is not clear. Although what I understand is that you would like to persist the filters. To do that, you could either pass the filters along with the calls or more likely put the filter in local storage and retrieve it from there.

Comment: Let say after edit/save, when I want to redirect to this path: `http://localhost:3000/admin/entry_exit_records?q%5Bid_equals%5D=123&commit=Filter&order=id_desc`, how do I get that path?